# Mongodb - Error after turning fork mode on

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.4

I am working on installing mongodb on remote server I managed  to install everything and tested it.

But when I tried to enable fork mode to make it run in the background via the command

`mongod --config  mongod.config`

**mongod.config**

```
systemLog:
 destination: file
 path: "etc/mongod.log"
 logAppend: true
storage:
 dbPath: "/home/peter/data/db"
 journal:
  enabled: false
processManagement:
 fork: true
net:
 bindIp: 127.0.0.1
 port: 27017
setParameter:
 enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false
```

this command is run successfully but when trying to run `mongo`
I get this error

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.9
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2017-09-30T01:31:07.048-0700 I -        [thread1] Invariant failure !driverName.empty() && !driverVersion.empty() && !osType.empty() && !osName.empty() && !osArchitecture.empty() && !osVersion.empty() src/mongo/rpc/metadata/client_metadata.cpp 350
2017-09-30T01:31:07.048-0700 I -        [thread1] 

***aborting after invariant() failure


2017-09-30T01:31:08.207-0700 F -        [thread1] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).
```

> Note: everything is working fine without fork mode

Any help will be appreciated.

**update**

**log file**

```
2017-10-01T08:07:05.786-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=488699 port=27017 dbpath=/home/peterw3/data/db 64-bit h$
2017-10-01T08:07:05.787-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.9
2017-10-01T08:07:05.787-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 876ebee8c7dd0e2d992f36a848ff4dc50ee6603e
2017-10-01T08:07:05.787-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-10-01T08:07:05.787-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-10-01T08:07:05.787-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-10-01T08:07:05.787-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-10-01T08:07:05.787-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-10-01T08:07:05.787-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 $
2017-10-01T08:07:05.813-0700 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /home/peterw3/data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' stora$
2017-10-01T08:07:05.813-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
2017-10-01T08:07:05.813-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTig$
2017-10-01T08:07:05.813-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2017-10-01T08:07:05.813-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected WT journal files.  Running recovery from last checkpoint.
2017-10-01T08:07:05.813-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] journal to nojournal transition config: create,cache_size=15451M,session_max=2$
2017-10-01T08:07:05.914-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=15451M,session_max=20000,eviction=(t$
2017-10-01T08:07:05.994-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2017-10-01T08:07:05.994-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2017-10-01T08:07:05.994-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2017-10-01T08:07:05.994-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2017-10-01T08:07:06.003-0700 W FTDC     [initandlisten] Error checking directory '/sys/block': No such file or directory
2017-10-01T08:07:06.003-0700 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/home/peterw3/d$
2017-10-01T08:07:06.005-0700 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017
2017-10-01T08:07:10.193-0700 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:33231 #1 (1 connection now open)
2017-10-01T08:07:10.209-0700 I -        [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:33231 (1 connection now open)
```

Comment: What is your O.S environment?

Comment: Godaddy Linux shared hosting

Answer (score 0):

Use full path with `path` and `dbPath`. So, both "should" start with `/`. When you are in fork, there is no "base" directory.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but unfortunately it didn't work after I changed the path to absolute path, still the same error

Comment: Have you checked what mongod.log says about this connection attempt?

Comment: kindly check log file output I added it in the original question

Comment: So, there is no error message about connection. One "strange" thing is in the config.. That "enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false", may I ask what is reason to it? Because you haven' t enabled authentication in your config.

Comment: no reason for that I just copied the config file from an example so I didn't change it, but anyway I tried to remove it but still the same result

Comment: one more update I was able to run with `mongo --nodb`